# Monitoring CPU cores runnning Hadoop tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cpu

Is it possible to monitor (view) the load of each processing core when running Hadoop MapReduce code? I'm using a laptop with Ubuntu and Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU U9600 @ 1.60GHz × 2.

Comment: Additional tools are probably required, such as Ambari, ganglia, nagios etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can Monitor the CPU, Network, Memory etc using Opensource tool Ganglia (GUI)

Ganglia is a scalable distributed monitoring system for high-performance computing systems such as clusters and Grids.

https://ganglia.wikimedia.org/latest/

**Hope this Helps!!!...**